# Proof of $|\int^{b}_{a}fg|^2\leq(\int^{a} _{b}|fg|)^2\leq (\int^{b}_{a}f^2)(\int^{b}_{a}g^2), \forall f,g \in {\mathscr R[a,b]}.$

Tags: real-analysis

There is an exercise in an  Analysis textbook that requires one to establish the
Cauchy- Schwarz Inequality: $|\int^{b}_{a}fg|^2\leq(\int^{a} _{b}|fg|)^2\leq (\int^{b}_{a}f^2)(\int^{b}_{a}g^2), \forall f,g \in {\mathscr R[a,b]}.$

I have managed to do so but I did not use the hints provided in the exercise(of which I have successfully established) as follows:

Let $f,g \in {\mathscr R[a,b]}.$

(1) $2|\int^{b}_{a}fg|\leq t\int^{b}_{a}f^2 + \frac{1}{t}\int^{b}_{a}g^2, t>0$

(2) If $\int^{b}_{a}f^2=0,$ then $\int^{b}_{a}fg=0.$

Hence, could anyone advise me on how to use that hint? Thank you.

Comment: Is your second hint correct?

Comment: @freak_warrior: What do you think :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\int_a^b f^2 = 0$ then hint 2 gives you the conclusion.  Otherwise, apply hint 1 with 
$$t = \sqrt{\frac{\int_a^b g^2}{\int_a^b f^2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ \int (\sqrt{t}|f|-\frac{|g|}{\sqrt{t}})^2 \ge 0$$ so

$$ \int tf^2+\frac{g^2}{t} \ge 2\int|fg| \ge 2|\int fg| $$

Multiplying by $t$ you get a inequality like this $t^2\int f^2-2t|\int fg|+\int g^2 \ge 0$. Now just look for $t$ minimal.